# How to move item from array after certain position and shift?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to manage a todolist with dependencies, it's an array with objects:
I need to take the child and choose the parent and reorder the items. There are only two levels of hierarchy.

```
grandfather
 father
  child
```

Example:

```
data = [{id: 1, taskParentId: null}, {id:2, taskParentId: null}, {id:3, taskParentId: 1} {id:4, taskParentId: null}, {id:5, taskParentId: 2}, {id:6, taskParentId: 3}];
```

I need an order like this:

```
1-3--6
2-5
4
```

I'm trying to order with this function

```
const swapArrayLocs = (arr, oldIndex, newIndex) => {
 if (newIndex >= arr.length) {
   let i = newIndex - arr.length + 1;
   while (i--) {
    arr.push(undefined);
   }
 }
 arr.splice(newIndex, 0, arr.splice(oldIndex, 1)[0]);
 return arr;
};
```

I take the index of the element with taskParentId and I give an index that's the next of taskParent.

Example...element with index 6

```
swapArrayLocs(data, 6, parentIndex+1);
```

Sometimes it's work but sometimes order is not respected...There is some order algorithm I can use to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The following should perform a clean swap between two indices. Put your logic beforehand and call it each time you want to swap two values.

```
function swapArray(array, ind1, ind2) {
  let tempVal = array[ind1]
  array[ind1] = array[ind2]
  array[ind2] = tempVal
}
```